# On Maui.net, Why is Android is not automatically scroll ViewElement into view when keyboard appear?

Tags: .net, maui

In .net-Maui, When I add a ViewElement in a scrollView and the keyboard appear, the keyboard is hidding the ViewElement.
If I remove the ScrollView it works fine, but then I can't scroll the content.

On Xamarin, Android will automatically scroll the ViewElement into view, so why has this changed?.

Do I have to do something different on Maui?

Here is an example of the code.

```
 public class TestView : ContentView
    {
        public TestView()
        {
            var layout = new AbsoluteLayout();
            var scrollView = new ScrollView { Content = layout, };
            Content = scrollView;
            var entry = new Entry();
            layout.Add(entry);
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(entry, new Rect(20, 600, 200, 45));
        }
    }
```

If I do this it works, but that's not a solution for me.

```
 public class TestView : ContentView
    {
        public TestView()
        {
            var layout = new AbsoluteLayout();
            Content = layout ;
            var entry = new Entry();
            layout.Add(entry);
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(entry, new Rect(20, 600, 200, 45));
        }
    }
```

I would expect, that the ViewElement was automatically scrolled into view.

Comment: On Xamarin, you had the same layout, including AbsoluteLayout and ScrollView? If you remove AbsoluteLayout, does it work with ScrollView?

Comment: Yes it worked on Xamarin with AbsoluteLayout in a ScrollView, Im am trying to port my app to Maui insted of Xamarin.
it makes no difference if I use another layout in the scrollview, I tried RelativeLayout and StackLayout, and it's the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help from Microsoft to fix it.

The answer is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1166483/why-is-android-is-not-automatically-scroll-viewele

From Microsoft:
To fix this problem, you can add the following code to the MainActivity and that will solve the problem:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustPan);
}
```

Comment: Glad you got help. To make sure this answer is useful in the future, even if link breaks, please copy enough description and code from the link, that the answer can “stand on its own”. This will help others in the future. Thank you.

Comment: The comment in the Microsoft thread really explains some of the view hierarchy and why ScrollViews fail when inside other views. It worked for me when I was using all Xaml for my UI build.